# GCDWebServer static website issue

Tags: ios, ipad, gcdwebserver

I am using `GCDWebServer` cocoapod and trying to start static code :

```
GCDWebServer* webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
[webServer addGETHandlerForBasePath:@"/" directoryPath:NSHomeDirectory() indexFilename:nil cacheAge:3600 allowRangeRequests:YES];
[webServer runWithPort:8080];
```

`GCDWebServer` not able to find `runWithPort` method.

[image]

Comment: Try to follow the example listed in the official repository: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer

Comment: are you sure it is `runWithPort:` method coz I have [Class Reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GCDWebServer/2.4/Classes/GCDWebServer.html) open but I am unable to find the method.

Comment: Yup the same example code is listed here - https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#serving-a-static-website

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the old method signature that the example is also incorrectly using and needs updating.  The new one is:

```
- (BOOL)runWithPort:(NSUInteger)port bonjourName:(NSString*)name;
```

Pass nil for the bonjourName so it behaves like the old method signature.

Answer (score 0):

runWithPort:: does not exists. It's startWithPort::.

The documentation uses both, but only startWithPort works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **startWithPort** method and consider passing full path of your directory to **directoryPath**, please have a look at my code example below:

```
private func loadDefaultIndexFile() {
    let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let folderPath = mainBundle.pathForResource("www", ofType: nil)
    print("HTML base folder Path: \(folderPath)")
    self.gcdWebServer.addGETHandlerForBasePath("/", directoryPath: folderPath, indexFilename: "index.html", cacheAge: 0, allowRangeRequests: true)
    self.gcdWebServer.startWithPort(8080, bonjourName: nil)
    self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: self.gcdWebServer.serverURL))
}
```

Hope it helps